# Android Jetpack Compose - Bottom Sheet won't expand after light theme change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-dark-theme

I'm using jetpack compose 1.0.0 and BottomSheetScaffold was working fine, but after I added a feature to change the theme from light to dark with a button, the bottom sheet won't expand after I change the theme. I'm handling the theme state using a property on the Application class. Here's some code:

Screen that's using the bottom sheet, this is on a fragment btw

```
MyAppTheme(application.isDark.value) {

    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            HomeBottomSheet(
                onCancelClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                    }
                },
                onDoneClick = { text ->
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            )
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {
        HomeScreen(
            darkTheme = application.isDark.value,
            darkThemeToggleClick = application::toggleDarkTheme,
            onHistoryClick = {
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.goToHistory)
            },
            onAddClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Application:

```
class MyApp: Application() {

    val isDark = mutableStateOf(false)

    fun toggleDarkTheme() {
        isDark.value = !isDark.value
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you writing wrong code? You aren't supposed to place a toggle or any jetpack compose code in your Application subclass. Why not follow any official guide

Comment: Can you help me? What's the right way to handle a global theme for the app? That can be applied and kept on every activity. Also, at first the isDark state was created in the fragment together with the BottomSheet, so I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a problem in initialization `bottomSheetScaffoldState`

Should be

```kotlin
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
     bottomSheetState = rememberBottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
)
```

Comment: Thank's you a lot...

Answer (score 0):

In release `1.1.1`, the `expand()` function was the following:

```kt
suspend fun expand() = animateTo(Expanded)
```

In release `1.2.1`, the `expand` function was updated to the following, which caused the issue for me:

```kt
suspend fun expand() {
    val target = if (hasExpandedState) Expanded else Collapsed
    animateTo(target)
}
```

To make the expand work with `1.2.1`, you have to set `sheetPeekHeight` to non-zero value:

```kt
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetShape = TopRoundShape(35, 35),
    sheetContent = {
        appState.currentBottomSheet?.let {
            BottomSheetContent(it)
        }
    },
    sheetPeekHeight = 100.dp,      // <----- non-zero value
    scaffoldState = appState.bottomSheetScaffoldState
)
```

---

The release I'm using now is `1.1.1` while waiting for latest stable release with the fix:

```kt
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.1"
```

---

You can monitor updates to the library on the [Compose Material](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material) site